# Why command is not executed, but automatically exiting?

Tags: php, terminal

When I run commands in terminal, they are not executed, it seems like it automatically answers "No" to prompts. What could be the problem?[image: terminal]

Answer (score 0):

You need to type yes, by default it's no.

Comment: i cannot answer, it automatically exits

Comment: Use flag --interactive=1

Comment: wait, have you changed some of the yii2 functionality like behaviours or before/after?

Comment: --interactive=0 helps, but the problem is not solved. And no, i didnt change anything.

Comment: how --interactive=0 helped it's automatically gives "yes"?

Comment: i think interactive=0 just doesnt prompt for user input so the command was executed

Comment: What the instructions you used to deploy yii2 on your machine? (link if possible). what php version?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230977/discussion-between-ivan-ponomarev-and-toms-eglite).